# How to query loans with Custom field in encompass?

Tags: c#, .net, sdk

### Problem:

I was unable to fetch the loan with Customer field in Encompass.

### What i have tried:

Below code i used to fetch loan with Custom field

```
StringFieldCriterion _flag = new StringFieldCriterion();
_flag.FieldName = "Loan.CX.FLAG";
_flag.Value = "Y";
_flag.MatchType = StringFieldMatchType.Exact;
 LoanIdentityList _loanLs = Globals.Session.Loans.Query(_flag);
```

### *Error*:

*Error executing query: Invalid column name 'CX.FLAG'*

Please let me the possible solution. Thanks in Advance

Comment: I'm interested in talking to people with EllieMae experience, if you wouldn't mind having a conversation with me reach out to me at mark.squires@ramp51.com

Answer (score 1):

Using the `Loans.Query()` method uses the ***Encompass Reporting Database*** on that field.

The reason it can't find your field is because of probably 2 things...

1. `CX.FLAG` might not be in the Reporting Database. If you use the tool to put it there... you should be good.
2. You might need to take out the `Loan.` in the field name... once you know `CX.FLAG` is in the Reporting Database... try the query with the field name as `"Fields.CX.FLAG"` to see if that helps you out.